# Add multiple customer Group IDs in some code - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, customer-group

How can I add additional customer group IDs in the code below? For example, add 8 and 9.

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId() == "6") :?>
   <style>
      .wpu {display:none}
   </style>
<?php endif;?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add them to an array, and use the PHP function [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<?php

$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$hideGroupIds = array(6, 8, 9);

if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn() && in_array($customerSession->getCustomerGroupId(), $hideGroupIds)) : ?>
<style>
.wpu {display:none}
</style>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $ids = array(generalGroup=>'6', specialGroup=>'8', customGroup=>'9'); ?>

<?php if (array_search(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(), $ids)) : ?>
      <style>.wpu {display:none}</style>
<?php endif;?>
```